# button that would redirect to a different form in yii

Tags: php, button, yii, yii-components

I have a cListview where users could select stuff they want to reserve but then after choosing those stuff I need a button to redirect to another form which could Identify the information of the borrower

the problem is the other form is located in a different controller/action
how can i redirect the button there?

help, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use, `Yii::app()->createUrl()`, method in your url-referral of button in `CListView`.

```
 'buttons' => array(
                    'Say Something' =>array(
                    'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("/controller/action/id/".$data->id)'
),             
    --options...  
 ),
```

Comment: notice, that in that `/controller/action/id/".$data->id` controller's action you need to fetch/store the 1st form's inputted data; otherwise you loose them.